# Reading from the serial port from C++ or Python on windows

Tags: c++, python, windows, serial-port

I need to read the serial port from windows, using either Python or C++. What API/Library should I use? Can you direct me to a tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your excellent answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python you've excellent package [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) that should be cross-platform (I've used only in GNU/Linux environment).

Give it a look, it's very simple to use but very powerful!

Of course [examples](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html) are provided!

By the way, if it can be useful [here](http://github.com/carlesso/pynokia/blob/master/pynokia) you can find a project of mine which use pyserial, as an extended example.

Answer (score 6):

In C++:

1. [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)`("\\\\.\\COM39", ...)`
2. [`SetCommState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363436%28VS.85%29.aspx)
3. [`SetCommTimeouts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363261%28VS.85%29.aspx)
4. `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`
5. `CloseHandle`

There is also a full documentation on [communication resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363196%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This is classic article about Win32 serial communications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In python it is as simple as importing **[pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)** and use its open() method (if you are using quite standard system, otherwise you have to adjust a number of parameters to match your environment of course).

*EDIT*:
As pointed out by Enrico, pyserial is not a default package in many distributions, so you have to install it by your own.
I suggest to install and use ***easy-install***, by **[setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)** to handle your python addons packages.

Comment: Just a point, pyserial is not installed as default in most system.

Comment: Right, it is simply available via easy-install. +1 for you as your answer was the first one :)